# Flash AS3 - How can I find out when all Loaders that are currently loading have finished.

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have some code where I am loading a few hundred images into an array in Flash. I am using XML to pass in the list then a Loader for each entry like this -

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.item.length(); i++) {
    imgloaders[i] = new Loader();
    imgloaders[i].load(new URLRequest(myXML.item[i].imageLocation));
    imgloaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}
```

I want to perform some action once all of these have finished loading. The only way I can think of is to increment a count each time one finishes and have a Timer that checks if the count has reached the number of images I am loading.

There must be a better way than that surely - Can anyone help?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a trivial class for this not long ago; feel free to use it if you wish.

```
// Joiner.as
package {
//Simple class to wait for several callbacks to finish before calling a single callback.
    public class Joiner {
        private var _count:int;
        private var _completed:int;
        private var _callback:Function;

    public function Joiner(count:int, callback:Function) {
        _count = count;
        _completed = 0;
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public function get count():int {
        return _count;
    }

    public function set count(v:int) {
        _count = v;
    }

    public function trigger() {
        _completed++;
        if( _completed >= _count ) {
            _callback();
        }
    }
}
}
```

(sorry for the messy indentation).

It's used like this;

```
var joiner:Joiner = new Joiner(myXML.item.length(), theFinalCallback);
for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.item.length(); i++) {
    imgloaders[i] = new Loader();
    imgloaders[i].load(new URLRequest(myXML.item[i].imageLocation));
    imgloaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event) 
       imageLoaded(e);
       joiner.trigger();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about flash/action-script specifically, I can say I have previously used this pattern previously:

```
onImageLoadedEvent
{
    count++;
    if (count == NUM_IMAGES)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same as what you suggest in the question, just no need for a timer to check the count.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LoaderMax by greensock, this is a really robust library for loading with many useful methods for grouping and monitoring multiple loader objects http://www.greensock.com/loadermax